# pyvmomi:error when calling RelocateVM

Tags: python, vmware, pyvmomi

Hi I am using pyvmomi API, to perform vmotions against a cluster when DRS is set to manual mode. I am going through a vcenter and querying a cluster and getting recommendation and using that to perform the Vmotions. The code is something like this.

```
    content=getVCContent(thisHost,    {'user':username,'pwd':decoded_password},logger)
        allClusterObj = content.viewManager.CreateContainerView(content.rootFolder, [pyVmomi.vim.ClusterComputeResource], True)

        allCluster = allClusterObj.view



        for thisDrsRecommendation in thisCluster.drsRecommendation:
            print thisDrsRecommendation.reason
        for thisMigration in thisDrsRecommendation.migrationList:
            print ' vm:', thisMigration.vm.name 
     while True:
            relocate_vm_to_host(thisMigration.vm.name,thisMigration.destination.name, allClusterObj.view)

#FUNCTION definition
    def relocate_vm_to_host(vm, host , allCluster):
        for thisCluster in allCluster:
            for thisHost in thisCluster.host:
                if thisHost.name == host:
                    for thisVm in thisHost.vm:
                        print 'Relocating vm:%s to host:%s on cluster:%s' %(thisVm.name,thisHost.name,thisCluster.name)
                        task = thisVm.RelocateVM(priority='defaultpriority')
```

I am getting an error saying the attribute doesn't exist.
AttributeError: 'vim.VirtualMachine' object has no attribute 'RelocateVM'

But the pyvmomi documentaion here https://github.com/vmware/pyvmomi/blob/master/docs/vim/VirtualMachine.rst
 has a detailed explanation for the method
    RelocateVM(spec, priority):

Anyone know what's the reason the method is missing? I also tried checking the available methods of the object ,that has RelocateVM_Task ,instead of RelocateVM(for which I couldn't find documentation) When I used that I get this error

```
TypeError: For "spec" expected type vim.vm.RelocateSpec, but got str
```

I checked the documentation for vim.vm.RelocateSpec, I am calling it in a function , but still throws an error.

```
def relocate_vm(VmToRelocate,destination_host,content):
    allvmObj = content.viewManager.CreateContainerView(content.rootFolder, [pyVmomi.vim.VirtualMachine], True)  
    allvms = allvmObj.view
    for vm in allvms:
        if vm.name == VmToRelocate:
        print 'vm:%s to relocate %s' %(vm.name , VmToRelocate)
        task = vm.RelocateVM_Task(spec = destination_host)
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a mistake in the documentation. The method is called `Relocate` (and not `RelocateVM`).

Note, BTW, that in your first sample you're not passing the destination host to the call to `Relocate` so something is definitely missing there.

You can see some samples at https://gist.github.com/rgerganov/12fdd2ded8d80f36230f or at https://github.com/sijis/pyvmomi-examples/blob/master/migrate-vm.py.

Lastly, one way to realize you're using the wrong name is by calling Python's `dir` method on a VirtualMachine object. This will list all properties of the object so you can see which methods it has:

```
>>> vm = vim.VirtualMachine('vm-1234', None)
>>> dir(vm)
['AcquireMksTicket', [...] 'Relocate', 'RelocateVM_Task', [...] ]
```

(abbreviated output)

Comment: I am getting an error when I call the Relocate/RelocateVM_Task, any ideas? I set the spec with the host. But it throws this error.
pyVmomi.VmomiSupport.ManagedObjectNotFound: (vmodl.fault.ManagedObjectNotFound) {
   dynamicType = <unset>,
   dynamicProperty = (vmodl.DynamicProperty) [],
   msg = '',
   faultCause = <unset>,
   faultMessage = (vmodl.LocalizableMessage) [],
   obj = 'vim.VirtualMachine:xxxx'
}

Comment: @jramacha Can you post your updated code in the question? Note that you have to create a new `vim.vm.RelocateSpec` object (you can't pass `spec=host`). See the example at https://github.com/sijis/pyvmomi-examples/blob/master/migrate-vm.py.

Comment: Actually it works now, I had a typo. I did spec.host = host obj. Thanks a lot